# jQuery several toggle triggers on same page

Tags: jquery, toggle, toggleclass

I have a page with two different triggers. They both toggle a "active"-class to the body on click. Using the togglemethod this works nicely if you click to open and then close the same panel again.

Anyhow, if I click to open one of them and then click to open the other, both show, and both individual "active"-classes gets added to the body at the same time.

Is there a way to determine if there is already a "active"-class added to the body so I can remove it when the other toggle-button is clicked before I show the one i clicked?

What I have at the moment in my JS is as follows. For the searchbar:

```
function searchToggle ( trigger ) {
    $( trigger ).on( 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').toggleClass('search-is-open');
    });
}
window.searchToggle = searchToggle;
```

And for the newsletter subscription:

```
function newsletterToggle ( trigger ) {
    $( trigger ).on( 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').toggleClass('newsletter-is-open');
    });
}
window.newsletterToggle = newsletterToggle;
```

Comment: Remove the other classes when one of the others is clicked. You don't have to determine if it's already set; since you don't have any effects that I can see, simply removing the other classes from `body` will cause the others to hide (or whatever happens when the class is manually toggled).

Comment: Also the `window.searchToggle = ...` lines seems odd; are you declaring the methods in some local scope? Why not declare it globally to begin with, or do `window.searchToggle = function(trigger){...}`? Another thing, if you're exporting it so they can be called by inline event attributes, consider using `addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: Ah! So it's so simple as that. Just add a removeClass on each of them. Thanks, it worked! My colleague have written the outline of this script, so the function(trigger) thingy is something related to our workflow which I'm trying to learn, so I can't really say much about it.